# Apache2 404 Error when accessing my websites from the internet

Tags: apache, mediawiki

### Problem:

I get the following error when trying to access a website on my homeserver through a different network:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at pocketwiki.cau.ninja Port 443
```

### Basic Information:

- `Apache2` webserver on `Ubuntu 20.04`
- Should run a [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) v1.35 over `/var/www/html/pocketwiki/` on `pocketwiki.cau.ninja`
- Should run a mediawiki v1.37.1 on `/var/www/html/pseudocodewiki/` on `wiki.pseudocode.site`
- Both wikis are fully accessible via `localhost/[wiki]`
- Both domains are pointing to my router, which has port-forwarding activated on `*.80` and `*.443`
- When accessing either of the two domains, a connection is made, and my browser corrects them to the relative wiki-domains. (For example: `wiki.pseudocode.site` becomes `https://wiki.pseudocode.site/pseudocodewiki/index.php/Main_Page`) but instead of the page, the error-message gets displayed.
- I have disabled (a2dissite) the `000-default.conf`
- I have enabled (a2ensite) both of the custom config-files (shown below)
- I have used [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) for https-access on both sites

### Details

My `apache.conf` (I don't have a `httpd.conf`)

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.

# ...

# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The `pocketwiki.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin XXXXXX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pocketwiki/
    ServerName pocketwiki.cau.ninja

    <Directory /var/www/html/pocketwiki/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =pocketwiki.cau.ninja
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The `pseudocodewiki.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` (basically the same file)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin XXXXXX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pseudocodewiki/
    ServerName wiki.pseudocode.site

    <Directory /var/www/html/pseudocodewiki/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =wiki.pseudocode.site
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Both wikis contain a `LocalSettings.php` with:

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/pocketwiki";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = "https://pocketwiki.cau.ninja/";
```

or

```
$wgScriptPath = "/pseudocodewiki";
$wgServer = "http://wiki.pseudocode.site/";
```

Sorry for the wall of text, I'm a total newbie on apache/linux and have read atleast 35 related articles/forum-posts which all asked for this information. (Obviously, none of them has helped.) If you want me to provide even more info, please add a filepath in your comment!

Comment: You have the document root for `wiki.pseudocode.site` set to `/var/www/html/pseudocodewiki/public`.  So, your URL `https://wiki.pseudocode.site/pseudocodewiki/index.php/Main_Page` is going to look for `/var/www/html/pseudocodewiki/public/pseudocodewiki/index.php`.  Is that how you have your documents organized?

Comment: No @Tim. My `index.php` is placed in `/var/www/html/[wiki]/` in both instances. I've read in a StackOverflow-article (which I can't find), that the public part is required. If I'd now change it to DocumentRoot `/var/www/html`, is the `/pseudocodewiki` then appended by the mediawiki, or do I have to write that in the conf-file?

Comment: Nothing is really required here.  If it were me, I'd have the document root be `/var/www/html/[wiki]`, and have the URL be `https://wiki.pseudocode.site/index.php/Main_Page`.  There's no reason to duplcate the Wiki title in the URL if you have it in the domain.

Comment: @TimRoberts Both domains now point to one wiki, and the other one is invisible.